# List of public Google Cloud Storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to get a list of public buckets on Google Cloud Storage?

I can't find anything on this subject in the docs: http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/gsmanager.html

**Update:** I recently saw a public google bucket containing patent documents. I was wondering if there is a publicly accessible list of public buckets.

Answer (score 3):

You can list your own buckets but there is currently no way to get a list all (public or private) buckets. This is probably good for security. If you wanted to know if a particular bucket is available, you can always try creating it and seeing if it fails. Can you  provide more details on your use case?

Comment: I just want to know if Google provides a list of its own public buckets.

Comment: There's no way to list any buckets other than the ones you own.